# Best way to get java.io.File MIME Type in java 8

Tags: java, spring, file, java-8, mime-types

To get the file mime type i'm trying to use :

`String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(document);`

but it always returns `application octet stream`

When i try to use

`String mimeType = Files.probeContentType(document.toPath());`
it always returns `null`

The type of the document that i'm trying to get its mime type, is : java.io.File

Any idea about how can i do ?
I'm already using Spring, is there anything in spring to handle the file mime type ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the file, whta do you expect as a result, and why?

Comment: The file is an java.io.File 
I'm expecting to get the mime type of this java.io.File 
as i can allow or no the upload of this file

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i used an object "`org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment`" instead of `java.io.File`

You can easily handle an Attachment

To get the mimeType you can use

```
public String getMimeType(Attachment document){
    String mimeType = document.getDataHandler().getContentType();
    return mimeType;
}
```

To get the document size you can use :

```
public int getSize(Attachment document){
    byte[] documentInByte;
    try {
        documentInByte = 
        IOUtils.toByteArray(document.getDataHandler().getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }

    return data.length;
}
```